# Can I Exclude Certain Pattern Matches In Rosie?

Tags: rosie-pattern-language

I want to match all five digit numbers except for a specific pattern.  So I want to be able to match `12345` but exclude `00000`.  Is there a pattern which I can use in Rosie to match this set of patterns?

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible.  Given the example above the correct expression would be

```
allButFiveZeroes = {!"00000" [0-9]{5}}
```

The `!"00000"` is referred to as negative lookahead.